# Spring, multiple methods on the same resource

Tags: spring

I have jhipster application and when I added one method more on resource (/user- get) then I receive following error:

```
UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'webMvcRequestHandlerProvider' defined in URL
```

Is it possible to have something like:

```
@GetMapping("/users")
getUsers()
```

and

```
@GetMapping("/users")
getDetails()
```

or I have to return only one DTO with both objects, or... return list of both objects? What is the best solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible according to the dispatcher to distinguish between. It needs  different url's or different http methods. In addition, it's not RESTful compliant to do so.

Comment: So better solution is send only one DTO or create list of two DTO's?

Comment: The smart elegant way is to use jackson json views (annotations provided). The simple way is to create dto's that fit your need, and seperate  methods.